# Using PLSQL, how can I read rows with blob field that holds a text file with a million numbers and insert into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, bulk-operations

I have a table with 20 rows. Each row has a blob field that holds a txt file. Inside the text file is a million unique 10 digit numbers. How can I read and insert those numbers into another table in an efficient manner using oracle sql and plsql.

Description of what I'm doing now:

1. I select the 20 rows.
2. For each row, I open the text file and read each line and store the number into a nested table collection.
3. I run a forall loop to insert those numbers along with some other fields into a table.

It works but takes a really long time. Is there a better way?

thank you!

Comment: You could create the files first with `PL/SQL` and then use `SQL*Loader` to load the data.

Comment: How long is "a really long time"? Given you are assembling and inserting twenty million rows, what do you consider a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Also, how are you reading the LOB file? The internals matter here.

Comment: Could you compare the execution of your code with SQL*Loading of the files alone. This latest should  be a lower limit of what you can achieve yourself with PL/SQL alone.